# Get wrong tableVIew.contentSize when use autolayout in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I use autolayout to autosize the cell

I set these:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But when I need to get contentSize.height of the table

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
print(tableView.contentSize.height)
```

If there are three cells in the tableView, and each height is 20

tableView.contentSize.height will give me height 150

but the real contentSize.height is 60

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your table view have header/footer?

Comment: It has no header and footer

Comment: This calculation is tricky with auto-sizing cells. What do you need the content height for? There may be another way to achieve what you want to achieve without having to calculate the content height.

Comment: I want to know if the tableView is scrolled to bottom

Comment: @MatthewHallatt - Can you please suggest on how to calculate the content height while we use auto-sizing cells ?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this could be a good scenario to use KVO (key value observing) to be notified whenever the contentSize changes. When using estimated heights it will often change, for example as you scroll and more cells are displayed.

Answer (score -1):

so basically it's depend on estimatedHeightForRowAt method 
For example you have return 65 and you have cell 50

than your max content size will be 65*50 = 3250 so if you have actual data more than table 3250 than u have to update estimatedHeightForRowAt return value :)